# Where is the Quantum Conundrum (Steam) save file location?

Tags: steam, quantum-conundrum

Where can I find the save file for Quantum Conundrum? I believe the game does not have Steam cloud enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I only have the demo, and it seems Steam Cloud is used.

Have a look at:

```
C:\{YourProgramFiles}\Steam\userdata\{YourSteamId}\200010\remote
```

Reference: [SPUF](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2792564).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the save files here:

- Windows: \userdata<user-id>\200010\remote\profile.bin
- Steam Play (Linux): /steamapps/compatdata/200010/pfx/